# How can I get the top 500 questions with the highest ratio of votes to views, in Data Explorer?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dataexplorer

Often I see a question with high votes and an incredibly high number of views, then a question with a lower number of votes and much less views.

I wonder what the best question is? The question with the most votes only got a small percentage of viewers to vote on it, while the question with less votes got a much higher percentage of viewers to vote on it.

I want to get the top 500 questions with the **highest ratio** of votes to views (by dividing the question votes total by the question views total: `votes / views`) from the [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), and display them.

Is this possible? How would it be done?

(I, unfortunately, do not even know where to start. I tried and failed so badly that it's not even worth linking it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt: https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/478114/top-500-scifi-questions-score-viewcount

I'd be curious to see what your attempt looked like in comparison; I'm sure it wasn't as bad as you thought it was.

Comment: This is perfect. (I couldn't even figure out how to select based on a ratio, somehow I ended up with a list of questions with 3 votes. ???) Thanks!